# How I can update my octave-3.2.4 to octave-3.6.2?

Tags: octave

I'm having Problems with using imsgesc and ginput in my octave-3.2.4 version and would like to upgrade to octave-3.6.2, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Download Octave 3.6.2 [From here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-3.6.2.tar.gz).  Save it to your hard drive and install it.  For information on how to install .tar.gz take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-file).

Answer (score 0):

Besides [installing the upstream version from source](https://askubuntu.com/a/170329/22949), you have a couple other options.

## Install From Quantal Packages

Octave 3.6.2 is packaged for Quantal (the upcoming Ubuntu release). It might (usually does, sometimes doesn't) work to [manually download those packages](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave).

1. Expand `3.6.2-3` under "The Quantal Quetzal (active development)".
2. Get the packages for your architecture--`i386` or `amd64`.
3. Get the ones for `all` architectures as well.
4. Put them in a folder that contains no other files.
5. Open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
6. Run this command:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -Ri foldername
   ```

   (You can drag the folder from Nautilus into the Terminal and it will paste its full name automatically.)
7. If you are told that one or more packages couldn't be configured, make sure you're connected to the Internet and run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   ```

## Use a PPA

You may be able to find Octave 3.6.2 pre-built for the Ubuntu release you're currently running, provided by an unofficial PPA. If so, this may be the best way to install it. But please [read this first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out) so you know about possible dangers from PPA's.

You can find some PPA's that provide Octave (though it won't necessarily be an exhaustive list) by going to the bottom of [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave) and clicking the green link that says "Other versions of 'octave' in untrusted archives."

In particular, if you're running Ubuntu 12.04, I'd suggest using [Albert Graef](https://launchpad.net/~dr-graef)'s [PPA for that version](https://launchpad.net/~dr-graef/+archive/octave-3.6.precise).

You can enable this PPA and install Octave from it by running these commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dr-graef/octave-3.6.precise
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```